# docker use common configuration in dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using many docker containers. I want to assign a static ip to one of them and use that static ip in `dockerfile` of an other one.
I want to use some sort of config files like `.env` file and use it in both of `dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to do either of these things.

If you are running both containers in the same Docker Compose setup, then Compose will create a private Docker network for you, and one container can access the other using its container name (or the name of the block in the `docker-compose.yml`) as a host name.  That should eliminate the need for a static IP address.

Secondly, hard-coding host names or IP addresses like this makes it a lot harder to reuse your setup.  As a very basic example, in development outside Docker, you might run the client and server on the same host and use `localhost` as the host name, but in a Docker Compose setup they'll be in different containers and use different host names.  This would also mean you can never `docker push` your image to a registry, which is needed for some common deployment scenarios.  An environment variable is a common way to pass this in from outside.

A `docker-compose.yml` that accomplished this might look like:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
    env:
      SERVER_URL: 'http://server/'
```

Answer (score 1):

I figure out a way. simply:

1. add the configurations to `.env` file like `ip_server=172.20.0.2`.
2. use `.env` variables in `docker-compose.yml` and pass them to docker image as argument like:

```
    services:
      client
      build:
        context: ./client
        args:
          - IP_SERVER=${ip_server}
```

3. then use it in `dockerfile` like so

```
    ARG IP_SERVER
    ENV IP_SERVER=${IP_SERVER}
```

---

references:
 - [docker-compose env file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env_file)
 - [docker-compose args](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args)
 - [dockerfile env](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)